# How to make rex to [ ] replace or split?

Tags: javascript, regex

I make rex to this string "root[0][1][2]". I want this string array([root, 0, 1, 2]) or String(root.0.1.2).

I tried make /["["]|["]["]/g. but, this rex ][ string cognize to contain ["].
And this rex ["["][^"["]* recognized the whole parentheses.

/["["]|["]["]/g   <- 1

or

/["["][^"["]*/g   <- 2

result 2 : root[0][1][2][3] => [0],[1],[2],[3]

result 1 : ["]["] => error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match anything but `[` or `]` with a negative character set:

```js
const str = 'root[0][1][2]';
const matches = str.match(/[^[\]]+/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple `replace()` and `split()` functions can do it.

```
var originalString=originalString.replace('[',',');
var originalString=originalString.replace(']',',');
var stringArray=originalString.split(',');
```

here, `stringArray` will be your result.